# Data format of trading view chart integration

Tags: javascript, php, charts, tradingview-api

I am trying clone the trading view chart api. I have checked the github sample that they have provided and found the following code:

```
  var _datafeed = new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed("http://yourhost/tradingview", 10000);
        var _widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
          symbol: 'AAPL',
          fullscreen:true,
          interval: '15',
          container_id: "tv_chart_container",
          datafeed: _datafeed,
          library_path: "/charting_library/",
          locale: getParameterByName('lang') || "en",
          disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings", "header_symbol_search", "symbol_search_hot_key"],
          debug: false,
          overrides: {
            "paneProperties.background": "#222222",
            "paneProperties.vertGridProperties.color": "#454545",
            "paneProperties.horzGridProperties.color": "#454545",
            "symbolWatermarkProperties.transparency": 90,
            "scalesProperties.textColor": "#AAA"
          }
        });
```

I understand that the data that is provided is given  from url "http://yourhost/tradingview".Can anyone help me to find the format of data that is provided from that url. Thanks in advance

Comment: Tradingview doesn't provide data for the library (beyond sample data), so they intend for you to build your own data transport layer. This can be in the format of UDF updates, or through their JS API. https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/How-To-Connect-My-Data

Answer (score 3):

Try to hit all these url with postman using get method. it will give you response with proper data formate .
1. http://yourhost/config;
2. http://yourhost/time;
3. http://yourhost/symbols?symbol=AAPL;
4. http://yourhost/history?symbol=AAPL&resolution=D&from=1505817294&to=1536921354 ;
5. http://yourhost/timescale_marks?timescale_marks?symbol=AAPL&from=1505741400&to=2114361000&resolution=D ;
6. http://yourhost/marks;

Replace http://yourhost/ with : https://demo_feed.tradingview.com/

Answer (score 0):

in component.ts use this code

```
customFormatters: {
    dateFormatter: {
      format: function (date) {
        var days = ["شنبه", "یکشنبه", "دوشنبه", "سه شنبه", "چهارشنبه", "پنجشنبه", "جمعه"],
          year = date.getUTCFullYear(),
          month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1,
          day = date.getUTCDate(),
          result = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
        return days[date.getUTCDay() - 1] + " " + result;
      }
    }
  }
```

And Also use plugin.js for persiandate

Comment: Do you know how can I pass my own symbols and my data to trading view charts?

Comment: @Afsanefda You should write your own UDF data feed API wrapper . I have written it in Python.

Comment: Salaam keivan aziz; do you know how to scrape historical data from tradingView site (or sites which use tradingView) without programming? (from chrome)

Comment: Hi @Mohammad_Hosein , Unfortunately I don't know how to fetch data from TradingView Site because We user TradingView Tools only for Tehran Stock Exchange but I heard you can global stock data from another sites and some of them have Api for Fetch data. I heard yahoo have some free Api for this action but it's free and have some limitation

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosein , Please see this link https://polygon.io/stocks?gclid=Cj0KCQjwqKuKBhCxARIsACf4XuGnxVi3Rr1hGUwxrjWvgu-ZY-mQ5KM8GFr-y1xZX1KpRDefdbdq_DoaAg-qEALw_wcB

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosein some samples and learning films in youtube are using yahoo finance https://finance.yahoo.com/currencies/